# Connect flutter app and python back-end code

Tags: python, flutter, flask

I am creating a flutter app that gets an image from the user. I then want to send the image to the python file and let it extract its text then send it to chatgpt. After it sends it to chatGPT, it should get back the answer and display it on screen. How would I connect the flutter and python files.

Flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class PickAnswer extends StatefulWidget {
  const PickAnswer({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _PickAnswer();
  }
}

class _PickAnswer extends State<PickAnswer> {
  File? selectedImage;
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Color.fromARGB(255, 114, 17, 225),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 46, 11, 189),
            ]),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 60),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _takePhoto();
                },
                child: const Text('Tkae a photo', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
         Expanded(
            child: selectedImage != null
              ? Image.file(selectedImage!, width: 390)
              : Container(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _takePhoto() async {
    if (counter == 0) {
      counter++;
      final returnedImage =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      if (returnedImage == null) return;
      setState(() {
        selectedImage = File(returnedImage.path);
      });
      return;
    }
    if (counter != 0) {
      selectedImage = null;
      counter--;
      final returnedImage =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      if (returnedImage == null) return;
      setState(() {
        selectedImage = File(returnedImage.path);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Python:

```
import openai
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2

myconfig = r"--psm 6 --oem 3"

# Replace with your image file path
vimg = cv2.imread(r"lib\math\right.png")

newimage = cv2.rotate(vimg, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(newimage, config=myconfig, output_type=Output.DICT) #C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe

amount_boxes = len(data['text'])

wordlist = []
vtext = ''

for i in range(amount_boxes):
    confidence = float(data['conf'][i])
    text = data['text'][i].strip()

    if confidence > 20 and text:
        wordlist.extend(text)
        print(f"Detected text: {text}, Confidence: {confidence}")
        (x, y, box_width, box_height) = (data['left'][i], data['top'][i], data['width'][i], data['height'][i])
        vimg = cv2.rectangle(vimg, (x, y), (x + box_width, y + box_height), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        vimg = cv2.putText(vimg, text, (x, y + box_height + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0))

for letter in wordlist:
    vtext += letter

# print(wordlist)
# print(vtext)


openai.api_key = "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"

finalResponse = ''

if vimg is not None:
    vresponse = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": vtext}])
    finalResponse = vresponse['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    vtext = ''
    vimg = None

print(finalResponse)
```